# Different sets of glyphs for aleph-numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

So I know the list of lists of aleph-numbers that goes:

$\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, \aleph_3 ...$

$\aleph_{\aleph_0}, \aleph_{\aleph_1}, \aleph_{\aleph_2}, \aleph_{\aleph_3} ...$

$\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}, \aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_1}}, \aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_2}}, \aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_3}} ...$

---

$\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph... \aleph_0}}}}$, $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph... \aleph_1}}}}$,
$\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph... \aleph_2}}}}$,
$\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph... \aleph_3}}}}$ ...

How do these levels correlate with the ordinals? Is $\aleph_{\aleph_1}$ equal to $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ or $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ or what? Where would $\aleph_{\omega^\omega}$ be? Is there an $\aleph_{\epsilon_0}$? An $\aleph_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_{\epsilon_{\epsilon... \epsilon_0}}}}$? And so on? From my reading it sounds like there "must" be, maybe?

Comment: If you're reading a book or another source that claims that $\aleph_{\aleph_0}, \aleph_{\aleph_1}, \aleph_{\aleph_2}, \ldots$ is somehow a meaningful segment of "the list" of aleph numbers, then you should be very cautious about anything else that source claims.

Comment: Note that alephs are indexed by **ordinals**, whereas alephs themselves are **cardinals**. Strictly speaking you shouldn’t have $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$, you should have $\aleph_{\omega}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: **Strictly** speaking, every cardinal **is also** an ordinal. That is why we **can** talk about aleph-fixed-points, which would be impossible if aleph-numbers were **not** ordinals.

Comment: OK so in the _Handbook of Fourier Analysis & Its Applications_ (Robert J Marks II) it says something on pg. 139 about Cantor messaging the Vatican about the meaning of glyphsets like $\aleph_{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$.

Comment: One more remark. Although I can accept that every ordinal corresponds to some cardinal, it is unclear to me, if cardinal and ordinal arithmetic differ, and if the cardinality of the set $\omega$ + 1 is $\aleph_0$, for example, and if $\omega^\omega$ does not equal $\aleph_0$ to the power of $\aleph_0$, how there should be a more overarching match between the two concepts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every ordinal $\alpha$, the cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$ is defined. Since cardinals are themselves ordinals, they fit into this order as well.

For example, since $\aleph_0 = \omega<\omega+1$, we have that $\aleph_{\aleph_0} = \aleph_\omega < \aleph_{\omega+1}$. Similarly, since $\left|\omega^\omega\right|=\aleph_0$, we have $\aleph_{\aleph_0} < \aleph_{\omega^\omega}  < \aleph_{\aleph_1}$

Some other important facts:

- If $\alpha<\beta$ are ordinals, then $\aleph_\alpha<\aleph_\beta$.
- For any cardinal $\kappa$, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\kappa=\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: This is all true, but I think it should be said explicitly that it is uncommon (to say the least) to use the $\aleph$ notation about something that you're using _as an ordinal_. So one would not write $\aleph_{\aleph_1}$ but instead $\aleph_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: @Henning Fair point! That notation is more suggestive of the definition. Though I have seen nested aleph notation before.

Comment: Also, since $\aleph_1 = \omega_1$ by definition, it *is* technically correct to write $\aleph_{\aleph_1}$.

Comment: I read somewhere that Cantor wrote a letter to the Vatican involving $\aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$. Anyway, knowing that $\aleph_{\aleph_1}$ is equal to $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is a major help for me since I have been working on a weird argument (in a weird version of axiomatic set theory that I have been trying to define) that $\aleph_{\aleph_1}$ was equal to the Continuum, and I'd seen that $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ was given as a "good option" for the Continuum (in some sense).

Comment: @KristianBerry: $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is indeed a possible value for $2^{\aleph_0}$ in ZFC, by [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) (though I don't know how it would be a particularly "good" size of the continuum).

Comment: My operating assumption is that for reasons of simplicity, if $2^{\aleph_0}$ doesn't go to an aleph on the first aleph-list, it goes to one on the next, and since for reasons of cofinality it doesn't go to $\aleph_ω$, it would go to the next simplest example, which here is $\aleph_{ω_1}$. There's more to it and I'm not exactly an expert so I don't want to throw all that stuff in to comments on a more basic problem but I guess that's why it seems like a good option to me (IDK why anyone else thinks it is).

Comment: @KristianBerry I'm not sure what's wrong with it being on the first list $\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\ldots$ Also, the next aleph after $\aleph_{\omega}$ (which as you note is not an option) is $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ (which is an option) not $\aleph_{\omega_1},$ which is much bigger. Furthermore, $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ is singular and although I'm not much of a platonist myself, there are various motivations (e.g. Martin's axiom) for believing the continuum is regular.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Apologies for "Easton policing", but Easton's theorem is way overkill for that... that's just plain old Cohen forcing.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Like I said my theory is superweird, but it involves an emphasis on the use of the aleph-lists defined more with aleph-glyphs than omega-glyphs. This emphasis is inspired by $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$, but beyond that I wouldn't be in a position to argue right now...